# Question on inequalities

Tags: inequality

I have this question and its really proving stubborn to crack.

Question: For how many $$a,b,c \ge 0$$ do we have such that $a+b+c=n$ and $a-c= k$. Here we fix $k\ge 0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Any ideas please?

Comment: If $n<k$, you have none.

Comment: @Gordon Shouldn't it be $n>k$?

Comment: Since $b+2c+k=n$, it should be $n<k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets deal with $a-c = k$ we know that $n \geq a \geq k \geq 0$

because from the conditions we know that $a \geq 0$ also if $a > n$ then the second equation will be always false $a+b+c=n$ thirdly if $a < c$ then $a -c $ will be negative which will break the condition that $k \geq 0$.

now we have $n-k+1$ choices for $a$ because $a $ can be equal to $n$ and then $c$ will have to be equal to $n-k$ or $a=n-1$ and $c=n-k+1$ and so on. every value that is valid for $a$ is between $n$ and $k$ so $a$ have $n-k+1$ valid choices.

if we pick a value for $a$ then $c$ is forced to a fixed value to fulfill this $a-c=k$ equation.

and now we have fixed values $a,c$ so b will be forced to a fixed value to fulfill this $a+b+c=n$ equation. so there are $n-k+1$ solution that fulfill your conditions and satisfy the equation but we need to make sure that $a+c \leq n$ so add to the first equation we get $a+a+c-c \leq n+k$  thus $2a \leq n+k$ which means that $a$ have to start from $\left\lfloor \frac{k+n}{2}\right\rfloor $ which the argument above apply to it.

so finally we have $\left\lfloor \frac{k+n}{2}\right\rfloor -k +1$ solutions.

as special cases :

1- when $k>n$ the above formula produce negative or zero answer which means that there is no solution.

2- when $k=n$ the above formula produce 1 as an answer which means that there is one solution namely $a=n ,b=0 , c=0$

3- when $k<n $ it's according to the above formula.

note : $\lfloor x\rfloor $ is called the floor function and gives the nearest lower integer to the $x$ for example $\lfloor \pi \rfloor = 3$

Answer (score 0):

$a = c+k$

$c+k + b+c = n \Rightarrow b = n - k - 2c$

$b = n-k - 2c \geq 0 \Rightarrow c \leq \frac{ n-k}{2}$

If $n > k$, you have $0$ solutions.

If $n = k$, you have 1 solution.

If $n < k$, you have infinite solutions.